# MEF and version compatibility

Tags: c#, windows, mef

I have a problem with MEF and version compatibility

Steps:

I've created three projects:

- Interface project (with one interface *A* which obliges me to have one void method)
- Export project (implements the interface *A* and realize a function that writes 'Hello world' to the console)
- Import project (Imports the interface *A*)

So what I do:

- Compile my *Export project* and put the export.dll to a folder which I will use in Import project
- Install my interface (InterfaceProject.dll) to GAC. (version 1.1.0.0) (to keep versioning)
- Run my import project

  - if I don't change the assembly version of my interface project (that my import project uses) everything works
  - if I increase the assembly version of my interface project everything crashes and I got a message ((ContractName="MyImportProject.IMyInterface")' is not assignable to type 'MyImportProject.IMyInterface")

Why does it happen and how to deal with it?

Comment: I've never had issues changing the assembly versions, however I also don't put my interface dlls into the GAC so that may be the issue here. I think MAF (not MEF) has better handling of versioning but that's just from memory and in joy sure it's even around anymore.

Comment: I've checked MAF and it seems a bit complicated plus that concept, when you must have a hard structure of folders, seems a bit strange for me
Nevertheless, thank you for your advice, really! (I'm already reading about MAF)

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to sign the interface assembly, because then MEF loads it only once, the first time, which would be your startup app.

Also, don't bump version unless you bump for all.